# How can we create table case statement on computed column without using view, function, trigger or procedure?

Tags: sql-server

```
{// code like

**

create table abctable(  
var1 int not null,  
var2 int not null,  
var3 as var1+var2,  
var4 as case when var3>40 then 1 else 0  
)

**

//
}
```

`var3` is computed column and we create `var4` as another computed column which depends on `var3`.

Only use create table syntax, not view, procedure, function etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat the calculation every time, like this example.
So it depends on how complicated and large your calculation(s) are, if you have to many then maybe a `view` would not be a bad idea.
Is there a reason you dont want to use a `view` ?

```
create table abctable(  
  var1 int not null,  
  var2 int not null,  
  var3 as var1 + var2,  
  var4 as case when (var1 + var2) > 40 then 1 else 0 end 
)
```